# My domain name is doubled in dns on my centos 6.5 vm guest. server.mydomain.com.mydomain.com

Tags: networking, dns, centos, ip, dhcp

my centos guest is set up as follows.  It gets its IP address from DHCP.

```
[marathon@server ~]$ domainname
mydomain.com

[marathon@server ~]$ hostname
server

[marathon@server ~]$ more /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=server.mydomain.com

[marathon@server ~]$ dnsdomainname 
dnsdomainname: No address associated with name
```

I think this is all ok.

But what ends resolvable by DNS is a different story

```
[marathon@server ~]$ nslookup
> server

*** Can't find server: No answer

> server.mydomain.com

*** Can't find server.mydomain.com: No answer

> server.mydomain.com.mydomain.com

Name:   server.mydomain.com.mydomain.com
Address: 230.230.65.148    <------- found it!
```

I've verified this on another machine.  server.mydomain.com doesn't resolve, but server.mydoain.com.mydomain.com does.

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: What does your `/etc/resolv.conf` look like? It seems like you defined an extra domain-name. I wonder... if you leave the hostname in `/etc/sysconfig/network` at just `server` (as it original was for me) and you get a domain-name via your DHCP-server if it all works ok. (or don't you get the `mydomain.com` via the DHCP-server? You should, otherwise you can't ping the fully qualified names of other computers in your network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your DNS server. I think you should check the zone file for mydomain.com on your DNS server. nslookup queries a DNS server directly, not hosts file.

You certainly can look also at /etc/resolv.conf - its `search` parameter is appended to single host name when you give it to a command line program (via system `resolver`). But you have pointed out yourself - error can be replicated on other machines.

So if nslookup gives you positive answer for server.mydomain.com.mydomain.com, then this comes from the DNS server, likely due to misconfigured `mydomain.com.zone` file. Look into that and please remember that `$ORIGIN` directive always must end with a dot. If it does not, it can give you exactly the error you are describing.

Correct entry should be:

```
$ORIGIN mydomain.com.
```

If you correct errors in zone file, do not forget to restart the DNS server.